# Suggestions for Android File Viewer - looping through a directory

Tags: android, documentation-viewer

Looking for a file viewer that could be pointed a shared directory with a list of files and have those files automatically shown for x seconds before loading the next file.

Reason - looking for a way to use the big android touch screen TV (a BENQ) to provide a rotating wallpaper of information easily. Something where files can be added and removed (PDFs, DOCX, JPG, XLSX, maybe a MPG, etc) (files name would be numbered to keep it in order)

I don't want to have to convert/import files to a PPT presentation. Rather was looking for something that was a simple copy/rename of files.

Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Personally I would convert them all to the same format, before passing them to the tool